# Split a sequential df, based on a timestamp, on a condition in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sequential df, based on a timestamp, that I would like to split when the distance value is greater than 1000.

The df looks like this:

`+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|timestamp        |distance           |id |
+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|1541712752000    |1.1990470282994594 |123|
|1541713551000    |1.5804709872862326 |123|
|1541714462000    |0.0                |123|
|1541715475000    |0.53107795768697   |123|
|1541716383000    |0.53107795768697   |123|
|1541716792000    |0.24740321078091282|123|
|1541717695000    |1542.00            |123|
|1541717801000    |2.7767418047706816 |123|
|1541718779000    |13.058715260118664 |123|
|1541719672000    |22.64146251404579  |123|
|1541720581000    |23.861007122654314 |123|
|1541721502000    |16.327504368653443 |123|
|1541722572000    |26.084599108380274 |123|
|1541723500000    |20.630034360787512 |123|
|1541724219000    |1893.00            |123|
|1541725264000    |23.16455204686255  |123|
|1541726037000    |15.911555304774817 |123|
|1541726950000    |20.057274313740784 |123|
|1541727884000    |12.967418789242549 |123|
|1541728085000    |2.720850595301784  |123|
+-----------------+-------------------+---+`

Based on the splitting sequential df on distance greater than 1000 I would like to have three dfs that look like:

`+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|timestamp        |distance           |id |
+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|1541712752000    |1.1990470282994594 |123|
|1541713551000    |1.5804709872862326 |123|
|1541714462000    |0.0                |123|
|1541715475000    |0.53107795768697   |123|
|1541716383000    |0.53107795768697   |123|
|1541716792000    |0.24740321078091282|123|
+-----------------+-------------------+---+`

`+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|timestamp        |distance           |id |
+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|1541717695000    |1542.00            |123|
|1541717801000    |2.7767418047706816 |123|
|1541718779000    |13.058715260118664 |123|
|1541719672000    |22.64146251404579  |123|
|1541720581000    |23.861007122654314 |123|
|1541721502000    |16.327504368653443 |123|
|1541722572000    |26.084599108380274 |123|
|1541723500000    |20.630034360787512 |123|
+-----------------+-------------------+---+`

`+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|timestamp        |distance           |id |
+-----------------+-------------------+---+
|1541724219000    |1893.00            |123|
|1541725264000    |23.16455204686255  |123|
|1541726037000    |15.911555304774817 |123|
|1541726950000    |20.057274313740784 |123|
|1541727884000    |12.967418789242549 |123|
|1541728085000    |2.720850595301784  |123|
+-----------------+-------------------+---+`

I'm using Spark 2.0.0

Thanks

Comment: Did the suggested duplicate answer your question?

Comment: Yes, the suggested duplicate answered my question.